# Power series with radius of convergence two.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence, analytic-functions, meromorphic-functions

Let $f(z)$ be a power-series (with complex coefficients) centered at $0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and with a radius of convergence 2 . Suppose that $f(0)=0$. Choose the correct statement(s) from below:\

- $f^{-1}(0)=\{0\}$;
- If $f$ is a non-constant function on $\{|z|<2\}$, then $f^{-1}(0)=\{0\}$;
- If $f$ is a non-constant function, then for all $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$ with sufficiently small $|\zeta|$, the equation $f(z)=\zeta$ has a solution;
- $$
  \int_{\gamma} f^{(n)}(z) \mathrm{d} z=0
  $$
  for every $n \geq 1$, where $\gamma$ is a unit circle centred at 0 , oriented clockwise, and $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$th derivative of $f(z)$.

In this how to prove inverse image of a singleton set zero is not a singleton set zero?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just come up with an example.... multiply an entire function with zeroes at $z=0$ and, say, $z=1$ -- e.g., $\sin \pi z$ -- by a function with a pole at $|z|=2$.

Comment: If $f$ is constant, then the radius of convergence of $f$ is $\infty$, not $2$. This does not disqualify the 2nd and 3rd statements from being true. But it does make their if clauses always true for all power series $f$ satisfying the hypothesis.

Comment: Do you understand what $f^{-1}(0) = \{0\}$ is claiming? It is saying that $0$ is the *only* value of $z$ that satisfies $f(z) = 0$. That is, $f$ has no other roots in its domain than $z = 0$. Is this going to be true of every power series $f$ that satisfies the hypothesis?